# HttpContext SignInAsync fail with Cookies and Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, claims-based-identity

I have a ASP.NET CORE application and I try to add a Login with Authentication with Cookies.

I have the follow code

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuth")
                .AddCookie("CookieAuth", config =>
                {
                    config.Cookie.Name = "GroupHome.Cookie";
                    config.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn";
                });
        ...

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
       ...
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
      ...
```

Login.cs

```
public IActionResult Login(LoginModel lm)
       {
           using (var ctx = new GroupHomeContext())
           {
               try {
                   var user = ctx.Logins.SingleOrDefault(er => er.UserName == lm.UserName);
                   if (Decrypt(user.Password) == lm.Password)
                   {
                       var employee = ctx.Employees.SingleOrDefault(em => em.EmployeeId == user.EmployeeId);
                       var employeeRole = ctx.EmployeeToRoles.SingleOrDefault(er => er.EmployeeId == employee.EmployeeId);
                       var Role = ctx.Roles.SingleOrDefault(rl => rl.RoleId == employeeRole.RoleId);

                       var GroupHomeClaims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, employee.EmployeeId.ToString()), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, employee.Email), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, employeeRole.RoleId.ToString()) };
                       var GroupHomeIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(GroupHomeClaims, "Group Home Identity");
                       var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { GroupHomeIdentity });

                       if (userPrincipal != null)
                       {
                           HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);  <----- ERROR IS HERE
                           return RedirectToAction("/Dashboard/Employees");
                       }
                       return RedirectToAction("/Account/SignIn");
                   }
                   return RedirectToAction("/Account/SignIn");
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   return RedirectToAction("/Account/SignIn");

               }
           }
       }
```

In the project I have configured
[image]

And when the user login all database verify procedure is ok, but when I try to set a ClaimsPrincipal into HttpContext.SignInAsync() get the following error.

[image]

Comment: Does your userPrincipal type match the one passed in by HttpContext.SignInAsync?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an async method **SignInAsync**, I guess you should then also await it and make the method **async**.